# Creating a transition probability matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays

I would like to create a transition probability matrix, like the
ones found in a textbook I'm using, *An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling*
by Mark A. Pinsky and Samuel Karlin.

The double bars are closer together than just using `||`. Also, the spacing between the index column and the bars, and the spacing between the bars and the matrix entries are narrow. At the very least, I would like to achieve these two results.

In addition, I would like to be able to create a matrix exactly like in Ex1:

1. The top indices are right-aligned with the matrix entries.
2. The double vertical bars are slightly thicker than the regular bar (although that might just be the font).
3. The double vertical bars are just long enough to reach the top entries and the bottom entries and are not longer.

If I can achieve these results too, that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far. I used the `blkarray` package.
There is too much spacing (black) and the bars are too far apart (red).
Thanks for the help!
[image: My result]

```
\mathbf{P} = 
        \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
         & 0   & 1   & 2 \\
        \begin{block}{r||rrr||}
        0 & 0.7 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
        1 & 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
        2 & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@{}` specifications.  Or see alternate approach that limits vertical line size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{P} = 
        \begin{blockarray}{c@{\hspace{1pt}}rrr@{\hspace{3pt}}}
         & 0   & 1   & 2 \\
        \begin{block}{r@{\hspace{1pt}}|@{\hspace{1pt}}
    |@{\hspace{1pt}}rrr@{\hspace{1pt}}|@{\hspace{1pt}}|}
        0 & 0.7 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
        1 & 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
        2 & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ALTERNATE APPROACH:

This uses my `tabstackengine` and `scalerel` packages to achieve the OP's goal of limiting the vertical line height.  I had to patch `\Centerstack` to omit the automatic `\strut` insertion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine,xpatch}
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}
\xpatchcmd\Centerstack{\strutlongstacks{T}}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stackalignment{r}
\mathbf{P} = 
       \Centerstack{
        0  \\
        1  \\
        2    
        }\!
        \stackon{
        \stretchleftright{|\!|}{\tabbedCenterstack{
         0.7 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
        0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
         0   & 0   & 0   
        }}{|\!|}}{\tabbedCenterstack{
        \protect\phantom{0.}0 & \protect\phantom{0.}1 & \protect\phantom{0.}2}
        \kern1pt}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! If you could also adjust the length of the bars so that it does not extend past the top and bottom rows, that would be perfect!

Comment: @maxtexing Using the current approach, I do not see how to shorten the bar length.  But if I think of a completely alternate approach that achieves that, I will post it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Where can I read more about the method you used, preferably a website? For example `@{\hspace{1pt}`? Also, it appears that if I want to include more columns in the matrix, I would just need to include more `r` columns and if I want more rows, just use more `\\\`. Is this correct?

Comment: @maxtexing The use of `@{}` specifications is covered in Lamport's LaTeX user guide (see description of `array` environment).  However, I have added an alternate approach, using my `stackengine` and `scalerel` packages to make the lines flush with the numbers.  I had to, in the preamble, redefine `\Centerstack`, to not automatically add a `\strut` to `\Centerstack`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the standard environment `{array}` (of the package `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. You can use them to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\begin{document}

$\mathbf{P} = 
\begin{NiceArray}{c@{\hspace{1ex}}ccc}[baseline=3]
  & 0   & 1   & 2 \\
0 & 0.7 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
1 & 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
2 & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [double] ([xshift=-0.5ex]2-|2) -- ([xshift=-0.5ex,yshift=0.5ex]last-|2) ;
  \tikz \draw [double] ([xshift=0.5ex]2-|5) -- ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=0.5ex]last-|5) ;
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]