# Formula alignment in a transition matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays, tikz-matrix, transition

I used the issue raised in the link below to build 2 alternative ways of generating a transition matrix for a Markov Chain.
However, as you can see, in the first version, my formula are losing their expected alignment.
And in the second, m column and row labels lose their alignments.

The link:
[Creating a transition probability matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267305/creating-a-transition-probability-matrix)

Could you please help me identify what is going wrong? I have tried editing a lot of this with no success.

**Option 1:**

```
\usepackage{amsmath, blkarray}
\[
\mathbf{P} = 
\begin{blockarray}{c@{\hspace{1pt}}rrrrr@{\hspace{3pt}}}
    & 0   & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4 \\
    \begin{block}{r@{\hspace{1pt}}|@{\hspace{1pt}}|@{\hspace{1pt}}
            rrrrr@{\hspace{1pt}}|@{\hspace{1pt}}|}
        0 & 0 & $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{1-1}$ & $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{2-1}$  & $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{3-1}$ & {$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{4-1}$}\\
        1 & 1.0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
        2 & 0   & 1.0   & 0 & 00 & 0   \\
        3 & 0   & 0   & 1.0 & 0 & 0   \\
        4 & 0   & 0   & 0 & 1.0 & 0   \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
```

[image]

**Option 2:**

```
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine,xpatch}
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}
\xpatchcmd\Centerstack{\strutlongstacks{T}}{}{}{}
\[
\def\stackalignment{c}
\mathbf{P} = 
\Centerstack{
    0  \\
    1  \\
    2  \\
    3  \\
    4  \\
}\!
\stackon{
    \stretchleftright{|\!|}{\tabbedCenterstack{
            0.0 & {$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{1-1}$} & {$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{2-1}$} & {$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{3-1}$} & {$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3}$)^{4-1}$}\\
            1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
            0.0   & 1.0   & 0   & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
            0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
            0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0
    }}{|\!|}}{\tabbedCenterstack{
        \protect\phantom{0.5}0 & \protect\phantom{0.5}1 & \protect\phantom{0.5}2 & \protect\phantom{0.5}3 & \protect\phantom{0.5}4}
    \kern1pt}
\]
```

[image]

Thank you very much for the help!

It is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the first option, remove all the `$` signs. Does the matrix then look like what you want?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that this worked... BUT, thank you very much for the help! Very quick and easy. Much appreciated.

Comment: Your original document gave lots of errors because of the $ signs. After errors, it is quite common that the output is not what you expect. You shouldn't ignore errors. If you use some editor or development environment that hides the errors, find out how you can check the log file.

Comment: @Didier: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/PwnqnmCF) with [`kbordermatrix`](//ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix) ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8j3o.png)).

Comment: also next time please post complete documents, the format above without `\usepackage` and the formula with no intervening `\begin{document}` and no `\documentclasss{..}` makes it harder for anyone to test your example as they have to guess the missing lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{P} =
\begin{VNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row]
  & 0   & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4 \\
0 & 0   & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{1-1}
        & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{2-1}
        & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{3-1}
        & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{4-1} \\
1 & 1.0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0   & 1.0   & 0 & 00 & 0   \\
3 & 0   & 0   & 1.0 & 0 & 0   \\
4 & 0   & 0   & 0 & 1.0 & 0   \\
\end{VNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The entries of a matrix, be it `XNiceMatrix`, `Xmatrix`, `array` or `blockarray` are already in math mode, so no `$` should be used. (The `X` stands for any of the allowed character for getting the various matrix delimiters.)

Answer (score 0):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{P} =
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={*6{c}}, 
    vline{2,Z} ={1}{2-Z}{},
    vline{2,Z} ={2}{2-Z}{}, 
    baseline=4
    }
    & 0   & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4 \\
    0 & 0   & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{1-1}
    & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{2-1}
    & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{3-1}
    & \frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{4-1} \\
    1 & 1.0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
    2 & 0   & 1.0   & 0 & 00 & 0   \\
    3 & 0   & 0   & 1.0 & 0 & 0   \\
    4 & 0   & 0   & 0 & 1.0 & 0   \\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]